# On Prem Zip Folder to Blob and Synapse views though SQL endpoints as source to data copy activity to Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, oracle-adf

I'm pretty new to azure and data factory and have two questions regarding data sources.

The start of my pipeline I need to connect to a shared on-premise zip folder and copy to azure blob storage. I know I need create a self host and connect to a file system etc but i don't know what file format to use as its .zip folder and the file type options are delimited, binary, excel etc?

My next question is I need to write synapse views which access the blob storage source, i know this is done though configuring SQL endpoints and creating external tables but i then need the synapse views I have created to be the data copy source to transfer the results of the view to an Azure SQL DB and don't know how to select the views as a source in my data copy activity?

Comment: Could you please provide what you have tried and any error if you got?

Answer (score 0):

To copy .zip file from on premises to Blob storage you should use binary dataset in ADF.
Create a binary dataset with file system linked service with `ZipDeflate (.zip)`  compression type.

[image]

Then you should be able to copy the unzipped file into blob storage as mentioned below:

[image]

For your reference here is the pipeline Json to copy Zip file from on premises to blob storage:

```
{
    "name": "Pipeline 2",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Copy data1",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "BinarySource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "FileServerReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "BinaryReadSettings",
                            "compressionProperties": {
                                "type": "ZipDeflateReadSettings"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "BinarySink",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobStorageWriteSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "Binary2",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "Binary1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

If the created views are in synapse serverless pool, then create Azure SQL database linked with Serverless SQL pool details with System assigned managed identity authentication as mentioned below:

[image]

Create a Azure SQL database dataset select above linked service for this dataset then you will be able to select the views directly as like tables.

[image]

For your reference here is the pipeline Json to copy views from synapse to blob Azure SQL database:

```
{
    "name": "Pipeline 1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Copy data1",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                        "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                        "partitionOption": "None"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                        "writeBehavior": "insert",
                        "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false,
                        "tableOption": "autoCreate",
                        "disableMetricsCollection": false
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "typeConversion": true,
                        "typeConversionSettings": {
                            "allowDataTruncation": true,
                            "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                        }
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable2",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've implemented the zip solution and that works great but for the solution that requires me to use Azure data factory to use Synapse views as a source i'm still unsure on where i can pull the view in as a source to then copy over to azure sql table. Any help with how i could implement that would be a great help, thank you! 

Comment: Where are the views in synapse workspace in serverless pool or dedicated SQL pool? Can you give the clarification?

Comment: @NaveenSharma - the OP never showed any work - only posting a set of requirements- the question should be closed - this answer is not l really helpful to the Stack Overflow community and site (there is no specific problem it’s solving - it’s a custom solution for someone)

Comment: @Bhavani - please refrain from writing custom solutions - you already asked the OP to show their work - that’s all you need to do - until the OP edits to show what they’ve done, along with all relevant details, there is nothing more for you to do - and no need to create any custom answers - that’s not what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: @Bhavani - also this question will likely get closed/deleted, as written, meaning all this work you did… will eventually disappear.